# Split one column into two columns with python pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, split, strip

I have a df of cities, that show as:

```
| id | location         |
|----|------------------|
| 1  | New York (NY)    |
| 2  | Los Angeles (CA) |
| 3  | Houston (TX)     |
```

And I wish use some kind of split/strip that give me something like

```
| id | city             | state |
|----|------------------|-------|
| 1  | New York         |   NY  |
| 2  | Los Angeles      |   CA  |
| 3  | Houston          |   TX  |
```

Or even if three columns, been one original and other 2 made by code.
I already try something like:

```
df[['city', 'state']] = df['location'].str.split("(", expand=True)
df['state'] = df['state'].str.strip(")")
```

Which works, but not so much 'cause there's a blank space after every city name and shouldn't. If I search a city, like:

```
df[df['city'] == 'Houston']
```

It will return nothing, but I have to code something like:

```
df[df['city'] == 'Houston '] # note the empty space after code
```

To give me something usefull, but that way gonna give me a headache when I made a merge or something like it.

So, someone have some kind of tips to hadle with this piece of code? I'm don't find nothing usefull in internet. It's always a simple split, or a simple strip. But I have faith that there's a more inteligent mode to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `str.extract`:

```
df = df.join(df.pop('location').str.extract(r'(.*)\s*\((.*)\)')
               .rename(columns={0: 'location', 1: 'state'}))
print(df)

# Output
   id      location state
0   1     New York     NY
1   2  Los Angeles     CA
2   3      Houston     TX
```

Comment: Kind of. I have few lines that doesn't have the the data as `City (XY)`. It's just `City`. When apply the code, it's give me a `NaN` in return. But already help me a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Well yeah why not `df['city'] = df['city'].strip()`?

Comment: Doesn't work. If I just type as you write, result the same thing (like `Houston (TX)` will return `Houston (TX)`). If a put something like `.str.strip("()")`, give something like `Houston (TX`. So...

Comment: Well yeah first you split on `(`, then you strip the `)` and _then_ you strip the final whitespace