# How to create 2 new columns based on values separated by "-" in first column in Python Pandas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have Data Frame in Python Pandas like below:

```
col1
-------
XX - YTR
AA - BRa
Nar - Op1
```

Based on values in "col1" I would like to create 2 new column by separate values in "col1", so I need to have solution like below:

```
col1      | col2| col3
-----------------------
XX - YTR  | XX  | YTR
AA - BRa  | AA  | BRa
Nar - Op1 | Nar | Op1
```

How can I do that in Python Pandas ?

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70267625/split-one-column-into-two-columns-with-python-pandas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `str.split`:

```
df = df.join(df['col1'].str.split(' - ', expand=True) \
                       .rename(columns={0: 'col2', 1: 'col3'}))
print(df)

# Output:
        col1 col2 col3
0   XX - YTR   XX  YTR
1   AA - BRa   AA  BRa
2  Nar - Op1  Nar  Op1
```